# Using KQL 'let' to combine two queries in the same table

Tags: let, kql

I am trying to learn KQL and had a query where I wanted to take 2 values from Windows Event codes 4624 (login) and 4634 (logout) and return them for different scenarios I'm still trying to build.

But primarily I would just like to be able to return the values in a table (print or project?)

```
let login = SecurityEvent 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| where EventID == '4624'
| project loginTime = TimeGenerated;
let logout = SecurityEvent 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| where EventID == '4634'
| project logoutTime = TimeGenerated;
print login
```

The error I am getting is "'project' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'login'"

What I would have hoped to see is:

```
loginTime           | logoutTime
----------------------------------------------
01/02/2021 18:46:30 | 01/02/2021 18:45:45
01/02/2021 18:47:30 | 01/02/2021 18:47:45
01/02/2021 18:48:30 | 01/02/2021 18:48:45
```

Would a join be better? It is in the same table (SecurityEvent), so I thought it would be possible to do it this way?

The dataset is from the MS provided Azure portal: https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring_Logs/DemoLogsBlade

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that "login" is a table type but `print` is expecting a scalar type.

```
let login = SecurityEvent
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| where EventID == '4624'
| project loginTime = TimeGenerated;
let logout = SecurityEvent 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| where EventID == '4634'
| project logoutTime = TimeGenerated;
print toscalar (login)
```

As to the result you are trying to get, I think this might be what you need:

**Updated to improve clarity/perf**

```
let login = SecurityEvent
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| where EventID == '4624'
| project TargetLogonId, loginTime = TimeGenerated;
let logout = SecurityEvent 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| where EventID == '4634'
| project TargetLogonId, logoutTime = TimeGenerated;
login
| join kind=leftouter logout on TargetLogonId
| project loginTime, logoutTime
```

Comment: A few suggestions: 1) remove the `sort by` in both queries, as `join` won't preserve the order anyway, so you're just wasting precious CPU cycles (and also reducing the parallelism of the query. 2) Instead of `| extend loginTime = TimeGenerated | project TargetLogonId, loginTime` just use `| project TargetLogonId, loginTime=TimeGenerated` - it's simpler to read. 3) It's best to explicitly specify the `join` kind (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator)

Comment: @genericUser - Amazing, thank you! That is exactly what I was trying to do. The course I am doing didn't really go into detail about scalar, so I am going to learn about it now.

Comment: @SlavikN Good call on sort by; that was actually left in accidentally when from testing. Also I wasn't aware that you could define new columns within `project` so thanks for that heads up.

Comment: Minor correction: in your edited answer you wrote `| project TargetLogonId, loginTime, loginTime = TimeGenerated`. You should remove the `loginTime, ` in the middle, and only leave `| project TargetLogonId, loginTime = TimeGenerated`

Answer (score 0):

I added some changes that encompass @GenericUser and @Slavik-N suggested and brings out the information that I was looking to calculate:

```
let login = SecurityEvent
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| where EventID == '4624'
| where AccountType == 'User'
| project Computer,Account ,TargetLogonId, loginTime = TimeGenerated;
let logout = SecurityEvent 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| where EventID == '4634'
| where AccountType == 'User'
| project Computer,Account,TargetLogonId, logoutTime = TimeGenerated;
login
| join kind=inner logout on TargetLogonId
| project Computer,Account,loginTime, logoutTime, minute = datetime_diff('minute',logoutTime,loginTime)
| where minute >0
| sort by minute desc
```